# Finding largest width of rects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsarray, cgrect

I am using an `NSArray` which contains `CGRect` values. Is there any way to get the greatest width of all the rects contained in the array through library methods, or do I have to implement my own logic? Thanks in advance.

Code sample:

```
for (int i=0; i<[array1 count]; i++) {
    CGRect rect = [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
// Here, some transformation of rects

[array2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];

}
```

In this code I am trying to take frames from `array1` and add them to `array2`. I am getting the frames in `array1` from XML. I parsed those frames and placed them in the array. I provided my code as a very simple way.

Comment: Posting your code can be useful

Comment: If I understood you correctly you have an array with the values of different frames. I think what you need is to sort them like you sort any array but sorting has to be done based on the width.

Comment: yes 7KV7 exactly thanks for looking on my question..

Comment: please post your code or provide us your array contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send a `-count` message to your array over and over like that.  It's wasteful.

```
float result = 0.0;
for (value in array1)
  {
  GCRect rect = [value CGRectValue];
  result = MAX(result, rect.size.width);
  }  // "result" now contains the greatest width you saw in the loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < [array2 count]; i++) 
{
    CGRect rect = [[array2 objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
    float widthTest = rect.size.width;
    //this gives you the width of each element. Compare and get the biggest
}
```